# how to convert buffer stringify from node.js to array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, child-process, sys

I have buffer json and write to python in nodejs this:

```js
const python = spawn("python", ["index.py"]);
//label = ["a","b","c","d"]
let label = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(label)); //<-----------------HERE
python.stdin.write(label); //<-----------------HERE
python.stdin.end();
```

and i'm read line in python this :

```
label = sys.stdin.readlines()
print(label)
#OUTPUT : ['["a","b","c","d"]']
```

How do I do convert is ['["a","b","c","d"]'] to array in python for use it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json.load`:

```
import json

label = json.load(sys.stdin)
```